# How do I manually add a URL as a bookmark in Safari?

Tags: safari, bookmarks

When I visit the URL it redirects to a different site even though I want the bookmark to initiate at the original URL. I don't see a way to manually add a bookmark with the URL that I specify, I only see a way to add a bookmark on the page I'm currently viewing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add a new bookmark (any site will do)
2. Navigate to Bookmarks -> Edit Bookmarks in the menu bar
3. Find the bookmark you just added and edit the URL/Title

Comment: If anyone from Apple Team is looking: please make it possible to add manually and make this workflow easier :(

Comment: I honestly believe Apple is doing everything to discourage us from using Safari these days.